# Why Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPoolTimer.Cancel() doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

UPDATE: This works in Windows 10 properly.

Here is a simple example:

```
    void testcase()
    {
         if (myTimer != null)
             myTimer.Cancel();

         myTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreateTimer(
             t => myMethod(),
             TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000)
         );
    }

    void myMethod()
    {
         myTimer = null;
         //some work
    }
```

What it should do is ensure that myMethod cannot be called more frequent than once in 4s and that myMethod shouldn't be called if there is already a newer call to testcase. Something similar with .net timers on desktop was possible. However, new call to testcase doesn't prevent previously scheduled myMethods from running. I have a simple workaround by adding integer callid parameter to myMethod and keeping track of it. But this above should work and it doesn't.

Am I doing something wrong? Does anyone have also any better idea on how to do this?

Comment: How on Earth could you tell the difference?  You cancel the timer but then you immediately create another one that also calls the method.  Setting the timer variable to null accomplishes nothing but preventing you from canceling the timer.

Comment: Well, I know the difference because something was not working as it should and then I have added integer callerid parameter in method which increases before every new timer, and then I can see which timer raised the method. Of course, I can workaround the problem this way, but it is not a question. Question is am I right that this should be working, but it doesn't?

Comment: Also, how on Earth does it work with Winforms Timers? :)

Comment: Your code should work how are you calling the testcase function? Are you not using the myTimer anywhere on the code?

Comment: Hi Pedro, thank you, I also think that it should work, that's why I am asking here. myTimer is not used elsewhere. I use this pattern in different parts of app, but let's say that one case is that it gets called when the ObservableCollection is changed.

Comment: Also of note - setting timer to null does remove the only reference, so it can be garbage collected. This class can't be disposed, but it would be also done here.

Comment: Your simple test does not show how you call testcase().  In other words, is it possible that you are not calling it before the 4 seconds elapse?

Comment: Is it possible that something else is setting myTimer to null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is called debouncing, [at least in javascript](http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/javascriptfunctionthrottlingan/).

A simple way to achieve it is to use the `System.Threading.Timer` instead, which has a handy `Change` used to reset it.

If you want to abstract it into your own timer class, it would look something like:

```
public class DebounceTimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private readonly int _delayInMs;

    public DebounceTimer(Action callback, int delayInMs)
    {
        _delayInMs = delayInMs;

        // the timer is initially stopped
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            callback: _ => callback(),
            state: null,
            dueTime: System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, 
            period: System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        // each call to Reset() resets the timer
        _timer.Change(
            dueTime: _delayInMs,
            period: System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // timers should be disposed when you're done using them
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Your test case would then become:

```
private DebounceTimer _timer;

void Init()
{
    // myMethod will be called 4000ms after the
    // last call to _timer.Reset()

    _timer = new DebounceTimer(myMethod, 4000);
}

void testcase()
{
    _timer.Reset();
}

void myMethod()
{
    //some work
}

public void Dispose()
{
    // don't forget to cleanup when you're finished testing
    _timer.Dispose();
}
```

**[Update]**

From your comments, it seems like you'd like to change the callback method with each reset, and only have the last one invoked. If that's the case, you can change the code to something like:

```
class DebounceTimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private readonly int _delayInMs;
    private Action _lastCallback = () => { };

    public DebounceTimer(int delayInMs)
    {
        _delayInMs = delayInMs;

        // the timer is initially stopped
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            callback: _ => _lastCallback(),
            state: null,
            dueTime: System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, 
            period: System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Reset(Action callback)
    {
        _timer.Change(dueTime: _delayInMs, period: System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

        // note: no thread synchronization is taken into account here,
        // a race condition might occur where the same callback would
        // be executed twice
        _lastCallback = callback;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When calling the `Reset` method, you can use a lambda to capture various method calls (not only `Action` methods):

```
void testcase()
{
    _timer.Reset(() => myMethod());
}

void othertestcase()
{
    // it's still a parameterless action, but it
    // calls another method with two parameters
    _timer.Reset(() => someOtherMethod(x, y));
}
```

As stated in the comments for the second timer snippet, the code is not thread safe, because the timer handler may already be running (or just about to run) on a separate thread while the callback reference is being changed inside the `Reset` method, meaning that the same callback would be executed twice.

A slightly more complex solution would be to lock while changing the callback, and make an additional check if enough time has elapsed since the last call to reset. The final code would then look like this (there might be other ways to synchronize, but this one is pretty straightforward imho):

```
class DebounceTimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly System.Threading.Timer _timer;
    private readonly int _delayInMs;
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private DateTime _lastResetTime = DateTime.MinValue;

    private Action _lastCallback = () => { };

    public DebounceTimer(int delayInMs)
    {
        _delayInMs = delayInMs;

        // the timer is initially stopped
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            callback: _ => InvokeIfTimeElapsed(),
            state: null,
            dueTime: System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, 
            period: System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void InvokeIfTimeElapsed()
    {
        Action callback;
        lock (_lock)
        {
            // if reset just happened, skip the whole thing
            if ((DateTime.UtcNow - _lastResetTime).TotalMilliseconds < _delayInMs)
                return;
            else
                callback = _lastCallback;
        }

        // if we're here, we are sure we've got the right callback - invoke it.
        // (even if reset happens now, we captured the previous callback 
        // inside the lock)

        callback();
    }

    public void Reset(Action callback)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            // reset timer
            _timer.Change(
                dueTime: _delayInMs,
                period: System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

            // save last reset timestamp
            _lastResetTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

            // set the new callback
            _lastCallback = callback;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, this is likely to be marked as answer, I omitted existence of System.Threading.Timer in Windows Store apps, I have already used it before so just that info is enough. However, it would be useful to know why that ThreadPoolTimer doesn't work if you have any idea?

Comment: I've played a little - actually I was using System.Timers.Timer before. As I have diferrent myMethods, this example doesn't seem like the best solution when I need to pass multiple parameters, while if I am not wrong it is possible with state parameter, it would require declaring custom classes and all in all too cumbersome... I guess there is no real good solution but this is the best idea and if nothing happens in 1 day it will be marked as answer...

Comment: Can you describe your use case a bit better? How do you decide which callback method to invoke in the end? Do you have multiple callers with different callbacks and you only want to invoke the last one which triggered a reset? Using an anonymous callback method with an `Action` signature can provide arbitrarily complex callback code (and capture any needed parameters), it's just that I don't completely understand how you are planning to use it.

Comment: No for one such pattern only one combination of parametars is possible, like myMethod(int par1, int par2), but there could be different patterns in different parts of the app (but they would be called from different testcase or different class in your example)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting timer = null in myMethod.  That guarantees that it will be null in the next call to testCase (so it won't be cancelled).

Instead, use TimerPool.CreateTimer to create a single-instance timer.  It will only fire once.  When your worker process finishes, the last thing it should do is initialize a new timer.

Comment: Thanks for being the first one who actually tried to think about the problem. However, that is not the answer. The problem is that myMethod should not be executed at all (or its executions should be postponed to some point), so whatever its code is doesn't matter, it shouldn't start if I call testcase once in every 4 seconds. It starts on every call to testcase after 4s. It shouldn't be like that.

Comment: TimperPool.CreateTimer doesn't seem to exist? Web search doesn't give some results and Visual Studio cannot resolve such class, so at least for Windows Store apps it doesn't exist.

Comment: Here's a link to ThreadpoolTimer.CreateTimer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230590.aspx

Comment: Hi Ivan:  Let me make sure that I understand the problem then.  So, you don't want for myMethod to be called on a schedule every 4 seconds.  Instead, you want a way to guarantee that no matter who calls your method, it will not execute more often than every 4 seconds, and that if someone does call your method while it is executing, that call will be ignored, not queued for execution 4 seconds later.  Is that right?

Comment: Mostly right. However call shouldn't be ignored if myMethod is executing, if no one calls testcase in 4s it should be executed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my self what is likely the problem, it seems that Cancel() is used only to cancel periodic timer from further repeating. I can't say that documentation says exactly that, but it seems that it is working like that. Thus if timer is not periodic like in this case, Cancel has no effect.

UPDATE: this works in Windows 10 as it should.

Comment: If that's the case, it's a bug.  The documentation and the provided sample code say that Cancel() will prevent the handler from running.  Consider calling CreateTimer() with third parameter, the termination handler, and see if it helps you any.

Comment: That's certainly not the case. Cancel() is supported for both periodic and single-use ThreadPoolTimers. Timers of either type can (and should) be cancelled via Cancel() if they're no longer needed. The only exception here is a single-use timer whose callback has already been invoked, in which case calling Cancel() would do nothing.